# Cadastro de dados em um array dinâmico retornando EAccesViolation

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou tentando criar uma procedure em delphi para cadastrar e salvar em um array dinâmico 3 variáveis básicas. Para isso, criei um array dinâmico global com o nome `Pedidos`, um `Record` TPedidoitem com id, nome e valor, e outro `Record` TPedido que recebe o `record` TPedidoItem:

```
TPedidoItem= record
id: Integer;
nome: string;
valor: Real;
end;
TPedido= record
pedido: TPedidoItem
end;
```

Como declarei o array dinâmico:

```
private
Pedidos: array of TPedidoItem;
```

Após isso, chamo uma procedure de cadastro que salva instâncias dos valores, adiciona mais um espaço no array `Pedidos`,salva esses dados no array e depois exibe os valores em um `label` da tela:

```
procedure TForm1.CadastrarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
pedido: TPedidoItem;
tamanho: Integer;
begin
    tamanho:= Length(Pedidos)+ 1;
    SetLength(Pedidos,tamanho);

    with pedido do
    begin
        id:= StrToInt(Ed3Num1.Text);
        nome:= Ed3Text1.Text;
        valor:= StrToInt(Ed3Num2.Text);
    end;

    Pedidos[tamanho].id:= pedido.id;
    Pedidos[tamanho].nome:= pedido.nome;
    Pedidos[tamanho].valor:= pedido.valor;

    Lista3.Caption:=Lista3.Caption +'Id: '+ IntToStr(Pedidos[tamanho].id)
        + ' | Nome: '+ Pedidos[tamanho].nome
        + ' | Valor: ' + FloatToStr(Pedidos[tamanho].valor)+#13;

end;
```

Tentei debugar para ver o que estava fazendo de errado, porém, o programa realiza todas as tarefas até o final sem demonstrar o erro, o erro só aparece depois de ter chegado ao `end;` do processo. Sabem o que estou fazendo de errado? Algo me diz que pode ser da forma que estou tentando salvar os dados no array dinâmico, mas não sei de que forma eu deveria salvar.

**Progresso(mais ou menos)**

Descobri o problema, o programa tentava salvar os dados em uma posição do array que não existia. Consegui resolver o problema de uma forma completamente ineficiente:

```
tamanho:= tamanho - 1;
Pedidos[tamanho].id:= pedido.id;
Pedidos[tamanho].nome:= pedido.nome;
Pedidos[tamanho].valor:= pedido.valor;

Lista3.Caption:=Lista3.Caption +'Id: '+ IntToStr(Pedidos[tamanho].id)
    + ' | Nome: '+ Pedidos[tamanho].nome
tamanho:= tamanho + 1;
```

Considerando o código acima, qual seria a melhor forma para cadastrar os dados com este array dinâmico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude a abordagem, onde esta utilizando:

```
tamanho:= Length(Pedidos)+ 1;
SetLength(Pedidos,tamanho);

with pedido do
begin
    id:= StrToInt(Ed3Num1.Text);
    nome:= Ed3Text1.Text;
    valor:= StrToInt(Ed3Num2.Text);
end;
```

Tente algo como:

```
SetLength(Pedidos, Succ(Length(Pedidos)));
vIdx := High(Pedidos);
Pedidos[vIdx].id:= StrToInt(Ed3Num1.Text);
Pedidos[vIdx].nome:= Ed3Text1.Text;
Pedidos[vIdx].valor:= StrToInt(Ed3Num2.Text);
```

Neste modelo você não precisa da variável `pedido`

Comment: Caso eu usasse um `for i:=o to vIdx`, para então fazer uma verificação com o id do array, poderia trazer esse problema de EAccessViolation? Ou funcionaria normalmente?

Comment: funcionaria normal, pois o `vIdx` começa em 0 e vai até maior do array, o correto seria `for i := Low(Pedidos) to High(Pedidos) do`